# How to put webaudio data in form

Tags: javascript, forms, blob, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the JSSoundRecorder(https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder) for recording a file on my website. I would like to send the resulting wav along with a form where I add more info. Is there a way to save the Blob in my form? So far I can only find a way to directly send the blob to the server using a Ajax request. Is there a way to put the result of the recorder in a hidden file or another smart solution?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to upload it as a file [1] (via `<input type="file">`) with a form, but you could try to base64 encode it and submit it via `<input type="text">`. You'd then have to decode it on the server before writing it to a file. This JSPerf has a few different methods of converting a Blob to base64: http://jsperf.com/blob-base64-conversion

[1] [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)